# Как правильно экранировать символ ? (знак вопроса) в PreparedStatement, если это не переменная связывания?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Следующий [запрос полностью рабочий](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=abb2fcb7a8e5990e2646da36048f09db) в 12c:

```
select *
from dual
match_recognize (
    measures a.dummy as dummy
    pattern (a?)
    define a as (1 = 1));

DUMMY
--------
X
```

Но он не работает через JDBC из-за символа `?`, который используется в запросе как часть регулярного выражения, а не как переменная связывания.

Как правильно экранировать тогда символ `?` в JDBC, если я хочу запустить запрос как `PreparedStatement` с переменными связывания?

**Примечания:**

- Нашел [дискуссию](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2013-October/000066.html) в списке рассылки: *обсуждения спецификации JDBC*, но там нет заключения по этой проблеме.
- PostgreSQL имеет [аналогичные проблемы с операторами JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370972/how-do-i-use-postgresql-jsonb-operators-containing-a-question-mark-via-jdb).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [What's the correct way to escape the ? character in a JDBC PreparedStatement when using Oracle 12c MATCH_RECOGNIZE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42108242) от участника [@Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/42108242

Answer (score 3):

Предложения, указанные в дискуссии: *обсуждения спецификации JDBC*  по ссылке в вопросе, уже реализованы и [документированны](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-3454411C-5F24-4D46-83A9-5DA0BA704F5D):

> **A.4.4 MATCH_RECOGNIZE Clause**
> The ? character is used as a token in MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause in Oracle Database 11g and later versions. As the JDBC standard defines the ? character as a parameter marker, the JDBC Driver and the Server SQL Engine cannot distinguish between different uses of the same token.
>
> In earlier versions of JDBC Driver, if you want to interpret the ? character as a MATCH_RECOGNIZE token and not as a parameter marker, then you must use a Statement instead of a PreparedStatement and disable escape processing. However, starting from Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), you can use the `'{\ ... \}'` syntax while using the ? character, so that the JDBC driver does not process it as a parameter marker and allows the SQL engine to process it. The following code snippet shows how to use the `{\ ... \}` syntax:

Фрагмент кода из примера в этой подглаве:

```
 "    PATTERN(A{\?\} X{\*?\} Y{\+?\} Z{\??\}) " +  // use of escape sequence
```

Проверить на работосппоссобность можно в любом инструменте, работающем через JDBC (не OCI), например, в SQL Developer:

```
select *
from dual
match_recognize (
    measures a.dummy as dummy
    pattern (a{\?\}) 
    define a as (1 = 1))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Важное замечание:** В документации [версии 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-3454411C-5F24-4D46-83A9-5DA0BA704F5D) и самой [последней 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-reference-information.html#GUID-3454411C-5F24-4D46-83A9-5DA0BA704F5D) предлагается совсем другой синтаксис экранирования:

> However, starting from Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), you can use the `{\\ ... \\}` syntax while using the ? character, so that the JDBC driver does not process it as a parameter marker and allows the SQL engine to process it. The following code snippet shows how to use the `{\\ ... \\}` syntax:

```
 "    {\\ PATTERN(A? X*? Y+? Z??)\\} " +  // use of escape sequence
```

Который не работает:

```
select *
from dual
match_recognize (
    measures a.dummy as dummy
    {\\ pattern (a?) \\}
    define a as (1 = 1))
```

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Является ли это ошибкой документации, или это новый синтаксис из более новой спецификации, пока не ясно.